# Разложение числа на множители

Tags: c++

Всем привет, надо разложить число на множители(определенные). С маленькими числами все работает. Как пытаюсь работать с большими не получается. Код такой:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

__int64 powmod(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 m) {
    unsigned __int64 res = 1;

    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return res % m;
}

void algorithm(__int64 a, __int64 b, __int64 p)
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution <unsigned long long> dis(1, p);
    __int64 n = 11;
    vector<__int64> vector1(n);
    __int64 **mas = new __int64 *[n];
    __int64 r = 0;
    __int64 e = n - 1;
    __int64 s = 1;

    vector1[0] = 2;
    vector1[1] = 3;
    vector1[2] = 5;
    vector1[3] = 7;
    vector1[4] = 11;
    vector1[5] = 13;
    vector1[6] = 17;
    vector1[7] = 19;
    vector1[8] = 23;
    vector1[9] = 29;
    vector1[10] = 31;

    for (__int64 i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mas[i] = new __int64[n];


    for (__int64 i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (__int64 j = 0; j < n; j++)
            mas[i][j] = 0;
    //выбор элемента, который еще не встречался
    for (__int64 i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            s = dis(gen);

            //возведение в степень и разложение числа
            r = powmod(a, s, p);
            while (e != -1)
            {
                if (r%vector1[e] == 0)
                {
                    r /= vector1[e];
                    mas[i][e]++;
                }
                else
                    e--;
            }
    if(r!=1)
        i--;
    e = n-1;
        } while (r != 1);
    }
}
        void main()
        {
            algorithm(5, 43, 1073676287);
        }
```

Значение s меняется рандомно, если не разложилось, то меняем  значение s и снова пробуем разложить, здесь это не указано. Само разложение идет в цикле while. Если взять модуль 503, то все отлично работает. Если больше, то он не может. В чем проблема?

Comment: может чуточку больше кода? что бы можно было скомпилировать и пробовать?

Comment: по коду не очень всё понятно, но  часто в подобных программах, программист забывает учесть переполнение при математических операциях, проверьте, чтобы при больших числах не было умножения или возведения в степень чисел, которые выходят за диапазон возможных.

Comment: Добавил кода. Просто, вроде тут нигде не может быть переполнения

Comment: сложный подход к решении задачи

Comment: Написана какая-то чушь в цикле `do { } while`. На первой же итерации этого цикла внутренний цикл доводит `e` до `-1`. После этого `e` навсегда остается `-1`, т.е. дальше `do { } while` ничего осмысленного не делает вообще - просто тупо генерирует новое случайное `r` и уменьшает `i`. И так до тех пор пока `r` случайно не станет `1`.

Comment: я просто лишнего кода убрал и видать нормальный, тоже удалил. Там e обновляется в конце.

Comment: `(a*b)%c =(a%c * b&c) % c`

Comment: Они там не превышают c